# mysql copy data from one table to another using foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mysql-workbench, copy-paste

`inputPreviewOffsetLeft`, `inputPreviewOffsetTop`, `inputPreviewSizeWidth`, `inputPreviewSizeHeight` are present in the `display_preview` table and `display`. `display_preview` has a foreign key `displayId` on `display` table.

```
INSERT INTO display_preview b (b.inputPreviewOffsetLeft, b.inputPreviewOffsetTop, b.inputPreviewSizeWidth, b.inputPreviewSizeHeight)
    SELECT bd.inputPreviewOffsetLeft, bd.inputPreviewOffsetTop, bd.inputPreviewSizeWidth, bd.inputPreviewSizeHeight 
    FROM display
INNER JOIN display bd on bd.id = b.displayId
```

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'b (b.inputPreviewOffsetLeft, b.inputPreviewOffsetTop, b.inputPreviewSizeWidth...' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to get `INSERT` table an alias name and I think you might want to use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` on `display_preview` and `display`

you can try the below query

```
INSERT INTO display_preview (inputPreviewOffsetLeft,inputPreviewOffsetTop, inputPreviewSizeWidth, inputPreviewSizeHeight)
SELECT bd.inputPreviewOffsetLeft, bd.inputPreviewOffsetTop, bd.inputPreviewSizeWidth, bd.inputPreviewSizeHeight 
FROM display_preview b
INNER JOIN display bd on bd.id = b.displayId
```

**EDIT**

If you want to do `UPDATE ... JOIN` you can try this.

```
UPDATE display_preview b
INNER JOIN display bd on bd.id = b.displayId
SET 
    b.inputPreviewOffsetLeft = bd.inputPreviewOffsetLeft, 
    b.inputPreviewOffsetTop = bd.inputPreviewOffsetTop, 
    b.inputPreviewSizeWidth = bd.inputPreviewSizeWidth , 
    b.inputPreviewSizeHeight = bd.inputPreviewSizeHeight
```

For more detail you can refer to [MySQL UPDATE JOIN](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/)

Comment: I need to update existing rows, it tries to add new rows

Comment: Ok.... But you used `INSERT INTO` in your question..

Comment: how do I update then

Comment: Did you want to `UPDATE display_preview`?

Comment: yes, this is want I wanted

Comment: @Andrei I had edited my answer you can try it